# При использовании pg_query происходит синтаксическая ошибка, а вместо вывода массива выводится false. PHP, postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

```php
$sqlSchedule = "SELECT p.placename as \"Аудитория\", w.weekdayname as \"День недели\", g.groupname as \"№ Группы\", sub.subjectname as \"Предмет\", t.second_name as \"ФИО\", l.lessontime as \"Начало занятий\", la.locationame as \"Местро проведения\"
FROM schedule s
INNER JOIN place p ON s.PlaceID = p.ID
INNER JOIN groups g ON s.GroupID = g.ID
INNER JOIN subjects sub ON s.SubjectID = sub.ID
INNER JOIN teachers t ON s.TeacherID = t.ID
INNER JOIN weekday w ON s.WeekdayID = w.ID
INNER JOIN lesson l ON s.LessonID = l.ID
INNER JOIN locationadress la ON s.locationadressid = la.ID "; // WHERE g.GroupName = '$setRequestSQL'

$res = pg_query($sqlSchedule);

echo $res;

if (!isset($_GET['schedule'], $allowed_methods)) {
  echo JSON(array(
    $res
  ));
};
```

Текст ошибки

> **Warning**:  pg_query(): Query failed: ОШИБКА:  столбец la.locationame не существует
> LINE 1: ..._name as "ФИО", l.lessontime as "Начало занятий", la.locatio...
>                                                             ^
> HINT:  Возможно, предполагалась ссылка на столбец "la.locationname". in **C:\xampp\htdocs\MetrostroyCollege\api.php** on line **33**
> [
>    false
> ]

Comment: `столбец la.locationame не существует`, а он существует? Может там две `n` должно быть `la.locationName`?

Comment: вы прочитали текст ошибки? внимательно по буквам имя столбца в запросе и в таблице сравнили, или что?

Comment: Действительно ошибка была в locationname. Однако все равно ничего не выводится

Comment: вы хоть справку по функции откройте и примеры посмотрите. Запрос вы выполнили, возможно, адже успешно. Далее результаты надо получить.