# Не выводятся никакие данные при выполнении запроса, не выводятся никакие ошибки. postgresql, php

Tags: php, postgresql

```js
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");

$connectSQL = pg_connect("
    host=localhost 
    port=5432
    dbname=MetrostroyCollege
    user=postgres
    password=postgres
    ");

if($connectSQL)
    echo "Соединение установлено";
else
    die("Ошибка подключения к бд");

$sqlSchedule = "SELECT p.placename as \"Аудитория\", w.weekdayname as \"День недели\", g.groupname as \"№ Группы\", sub.subjectname as \"Предмет\", t.second_name as \"ФИО\", l.lessontime as \"Начало занятий\", la.locationname as \"Местро проведения\"
FROM schedule s
    INNER JOIN place p ON s.PlaceID = p.ID
    INNER JOIN groups g ON s.GroupID = g.ID
    INNER JOIN subjects sub ON s.SubjectID = sub.ID
    INNER JOIN teachers t ON s.TeacherID = t.ID
    INNER JOIN weekday w ON s.WeekdayID = w.ID
    INNER JOIN lesson l ON s.LessonID = l.ID
    INNER JOIN locationadress la ON s.locationadressid = la.ID"; // WHERE g.GroupName = '$setRequestSQL'

$res = pg_query($connectSQL, $sqlSchedule);

if(!isset($_GET['schedule'], $allowed_methods)) {
    echo JSON (array(
        $res
    ));
};
```

Вывод:

```
Соединение установлено[
    {}
]
```

IDE жалуется на таблицы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

данные в базе данных есть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. Попробуй в коде явно указать схемы для таблиц, к которым идёт обращение в запросе.
У тебя, как я понимаю, они в public - попробуй проставить public.schedule, public.place и т.д. 2. Попробуй выполнить этот же запрос в БД. Может, он просто ничего не находит? То, что в таблицах данные есть, ещё ничего не значит. Выборка, при этом, всё равно может быть пустой.

Comment: У вас в примере код в джойне куча таблиц, в то время как вы показываете вывод из БД 1й таблицы. Выполните ваш запрос из кода в БД и посмотрите, будут ли данные отбираться вообще?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [При использовании pg\_query происходит синтаксическая ошибка, а вместо вывода массива выводится false. PHP, postgresql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1494331/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-pg-query-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81)

Comment: То что IDE жалуется на таблицы это значит что настройки IDE не корректны, на работу запроса это не влияет, ылните свой запрос с кучей join  в админке и посмотрите результат, скорее всего, его не будет.